# why does the higgs mechanism need to exist?

Tags: standard-model, higgs

I feel like this is kind of a pleb question but I'm gonna ask it anyway. As far as I know, mass is fundamentally the property that a field has when it can have energy without having momentum. But why is it necessary to introduce a scalar field that gives the fermion, quark, and weak boson fields mass upon its symmetry breaking? I watched the Susskind lectures on the standard model a long time ago and I feel like I should understand this but I've forgotten...Thank you.

Comment: Pleb???????????

Comment: It is not necessary to do it this way, it just seems to be the easiest way. You need to keep in mind that the standard model is not a fundamental theory. It's a phenomenological low energy mean field theory of a fundamental field theory that we don't know, yet. It may be string theory or something else... somebody in the future will surely have the right idea. For now all the particles that you know, including the Higgs, are just fits to the data and there is nothing fundamental about them. The Higgs, by the way, is not responsible for the mass of matter.

Comment: "Pleb" is a term senior Tory politicians in the UK may or may not use when asking police officers permission to cycle through the main gates at Downing Street. Possibly.

Comment: What do you mean by "necessary"? It's not "necessary", but it turns out that's the way it works in the world.

Comment: @CuriousOne: you say the higgs doesn't give mass to matter but I thought the higgs field give mass to the fermions via the yukawa interaction or smthn

Comment: @EbenCowley: What I meant to say is that the total contribution of the Higgs field to total mass in the universe is below one percent, if I am not mistaken. It's also not obvious if the interpretation that electron actually gets its mass from the Higgs is correct. That's a theoretical construct to fit the data, not an experimentally testable hypothesis... after all, one can't just turn the Higgs field off and weigh the now bare electron, again. What we can say is that whatever the vacuum is, it differentiates into these fields, including the Higgs, at below 1TeV.

Answer (score 2):

What I have retained from lectures on symmetry breaking is that when trying to write a unified Lagrangian for weak and electromagnetic interactions, one is faced with the fact that the electromagnetic interaction  has infinite range and thus can exchange a zero mass particle, the photon,   the weak, because it experimentally has a small range , must have massive exchange particles. Thus the symmetry attempted is broken in the data.

The solution is to assume that at high energies the symmetries are perfect and all gauge bosons exchanged in electroweak interactions have mass zero. This symmetry must be broken by some mechanism at the energies we had studied up to the time that the model was proposed and give masses to the gauge bosons of the weak interaction below a certain energy in the interaction. An economic proposal was the Higgs field. There is this useful  FAQ on the  the [Higgs field](http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/the-higgs-particle/the-higgs-faq-2-0/)

The Higgs field mechanism is not the only proposal for symmetry breaking, as there exist other ones. I remember [technicolor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor_%28physics%29) theories also have a solution for the mass.

The fairly recent discovery of the  [Higgs boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson)   at the LHC  confirms the existence of the [Higgs field](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/unify.html), because even in the simplest model a Higgs boson should exist as an manifestation of the  field.